# What does pressing Alt+Shift+3 do in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

What does pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> in Terminal do?

All I can see is that it prints a pound sign and jumps to the next line, but, supposedly, it does something special.

Comment: What shell is this supposed to be answered for?

Comment: I get a heart for when I do alt+shift+3, but it may be different on your end.

Answer (score 3):

In readline, <kbd>Alt</kbd> can be interpreted as `\e`. On my system (and likely yours as well) `\e#` is bound to `insert-comment`, which according to the `bash(1)` man page comments or uncomments the current command line and executes it. If you press it without typing anything then `#` is executed, which has no effect since it's a comment.

Comment: Unless you are, like me, using `ksh` with Vi key bindings, in which case no `#` is inserted when nothing yet has been typed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the layout. In my case it creates ¥ character.

Comment: Did you perhaps think the asker meant AltGr-#?

Comment: No, as I said, it depends on the layout. I don't have AltGr on my keyboard at all.

Comment: @macias Are you sure about this? *`AltGr`* is usually just an alias for "right `Alt` key". Does the same appear when you use the left `Alt` (assuming you have one)?